# Can you let me know how you would analyze/compare this 2 box plots?

Tags: boxplot

[image]

I am unsure of what these 2 box plots are telling me about the distribution of the data and how the are different. Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Females = 0 group seems to be slightly skewed to the right (to the higher end.) No extreme points.

The Females = 1 has this funny situation that the median is also the bottom of the box. This usually is caused by too litter variation at the low end (so that your median and 25th percentile happened to be 4) or very low sample size. There are also two extreme points: id 24 is more than 1.5*inter-quartile range away from the top of the box; and id 50 is 1.5*inter-quartile range lower than the bottom of the box.

It looks like your data are whole numbers ranging form 2 to 7, I think bar plot may be a more appropriate tool to visualize them.

Answer (score 0):

Box plots give us information about the **center** and **spread** of data. In a typical boxplot, the line in the box represents the median value of the data; that is, the value such that 50% of the data are above and 50% of the data are below that value. The boxes typically represent the interquartile range, or the middle 50% of the data. The "whiskers," the lines extending from the boxes, represent the top and bottom 25% of the data, excluding outliers. The individual points beyond the whiskers are outliers (or at least lie significantly beyond the range of the rest of the data).